# Grids with separate eventhandler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have two overlapping grids.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid Name="gridMain" KeyDown="GridMain_KeyDown">
  </Grid>
  <Grid Name="gridSecond" KeyDown="GridSecond_KeyDown">
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Once I'm done with main screen, I disable (make invisible) the main screen and enable (make visible) the second screen.  I also have separate KeyDown event handler for each Grid.  When the second grid is visible, the GridSecond_KeyDown is never fired.  Can someone tell me why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Do you make those grids to fill all available area? I mean, if first grid is visible it overlaps second?

Comment: Yes. First overlaps the second. Same dimensions and location.

Comment: In your case first I would not Show/Hide them but set different, clearly visible different background colors to both and see if after that first becomes "invisible" it still covers second so blocking in that way event handling.

Comment: I changed the color of the two grids... when the first becomes invisible, the grid changes color to the second.

Comment: I suspect it does not have focus.  I would put them in different rows and collapse (not hide).

Comment: @BalamBalam: I'm not talking about datagrid. Just WPF Grid.

Here is an update of what I've tried.  I've moved the eventhandler to the parent "Grid".  But when the maingrid is made invisible, and gridsecond comes into view, the eventhandler is also disabled... even though gridsecond is also inside "GRID"

Comment: An I am talking Grid.  Create explicit Row and Columns

Comment: Thanks all for your help. This was due to KeyDown ignoring certain keys. Ie. down arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. In retrospect I didn't know enough at the time to ask the right question....

[KeyDown event not firing with .NET WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608611/keydown-event-not-firing-with-net-winforms)