# Form not reading arrow key in keydown event

Tags: vb.net

im programming a form that moves a picturebox left or right a certain distance based on arrow key presses. I am aware that the form needs KeyPreveiw = True, and is set accordingly. my code is:

```
Public Sub frmGame_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        leftorright = -1
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        leftorright = 1
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        upordown = -1
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        upordown = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

In this block, WASD works accordingly, however LRUD arrows do not trigger at all. I tried using:

```
Msgbox(e.keycode.tostring())
```

to show if they were firing off, other buttons worked (123, ABC, etc), the arrows however did not. My guess on the problem is that i have buttons on the form, and they are taking the keypresses for themselves (priority over the form). On my form i have 3 buttons, when i press lets say the down arrow, i can see each button be highlighted going through the three. How can i fix this problem? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: After removing the button, the code works. I need to figure out how to make the form take priority over the button if possible :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyDown event not firing with .NET WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608611/keydown-event-not-firing-with-net-winforms)

Answer (score 4):

Override ProcessCmdKey() for your Form like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.Up
                Debug.Print("Up")
                Return True ' <-- If you want to suppress default handling of arrow keys

            Case Keys.Right
                Debug.Print("Right")
                Return True ' <-- If you want to suppress default handling of arrow keys

            Case Keys.Down
                Debug.Print("Down")
                Return True ' <-- If you want to suppress default handling of arrow keys

            Case Keys.Left
                Debug.Print("Left")
                Return True ' <-- If you want to suppress default handling of arrow keys

        End Select
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

End Class
```