# How to use keydown event to display a message box

Tags: vb.net

This is my code it will display a message box when the letter a from the keyboard is pressed. but the thing is when i press the a it doesn't trigger i don't know why? 
 i'm a new-bee, can anyone help me? (sorry for the english)

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        msgbox("SUCCES")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: forms dont monitor the keyboard unless you set `KeyPreview` to true

Comment: sir the keypreview property of my form is true

Comment: this will only work if you are focused on the forum. So if you are focused on a text box or panel it won't work.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608611/keydown-event-not-firing-with-net-winforms?rq=1) post can help: