# Keypress event to trigger ButtonClick Event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Bit of a newbie to vb here, having a problem with a game I am making.

When the 1 key is pressed, I want a button click event to be triggered. I was able to get it to somewhat work in a testing program, but the issue I am having seems to be based around focus. When this form page loads, a different button is in focus, and so my keypress seems not to register. This is the code I have written for the keypress event. I am going to have to have similar code for 2,3 and 4.

```
Private Sub OneKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
  If e.KeyData = Keys.D1 Then
    Me.Ans1Btn.PerformClick()
  End If
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1616965/17034)

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! So the code that I want to execute, `Me.Ans1Btn.PerformClick()` Belongs in the first part of the IF statement? What does the else clause actually do?

Comment: When you override a virtual method then you generally need to call the base method when you decide not to do anything custom.